# Angular variable not ready until promise but is used in page causing undefined errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to be clear, I know why my variable is undefined.

I have an object called section which I instantiate at the top of the page with:

```
section: Section;
```

Later down into the `ngOnInit` function I am using a promise to return a value from local storage which I then set = to the section variable like so:

```
this.storage.get(CERTIFICATE).then(res => {
  this.certificate = JSON.parse(res);

  this.storage.get(SECTION).then(uuid => {
    this.certificate.sections.forEach(section => {
      if (section.uuid !== uuid) {
        return;
      }

      this.section = section;
    });
  });
});
```

This all works perfectly well, I then am using this section variable in my sections.page.html for example:

```
<app-section [section]="section"></app-section>
```

However, when the page loads it gives me a section is undefined error, which I get it is and then when the promise returns almost instantly the page loads as expected.

How can I avoid this error? I have tried using:

```
section: Section = new Section();
```

However that gives me the same problem.

Section model looks like this:

```
import {Question} from './Question';

export class Section {
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
  title: string;
  questions: Question[];
}
```

Is it because I don't have a 'constructor' or is there another way to avoid this pesky error?

```
ERROR TypeError: "_co.section is undefined"
```

Comment: Where do you use `_co.section`? None of you examples contain that variable.

Comment: It's part of the angular markup for errors, nothing user controlled. Just the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach is actually a filtering. You can do something like this.

```
this.storage.get(CERTIFICATE).then(res => {
  this.certificate = JSON.parse(res);

  this.storage.get(SECTION).then(uuid => {
    this.section = this.certificate.sections.filter(section => section.uuid === uuid);
  });
});
```

Comment: Will be implementing, much prefer that markup thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this error by using [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) like this:

take one flag variable  `isDataLoaded = false` on top

Than use this variable in your ngOnint function like this

this.storage.get(CERTIFICATE).then(res => {
  this.certificate = JSON.parse(res);

```
this.storage.get(SECTION).then(uuid => {
    this.certificate.sections.forEach(section => {
      if (section.uuid !== uuid) {
        return;
      }
      this.isDataLoaded = true;
      this.section = section;
    });
  });
});



<app-section *ngIf="isDataLoaded" [section]="section"></app-section>
```

Once `section.id` have value than after this section enter in dom so you don't have `undefined` error anymore.

Comment: In your example if section is undefined you'll get an error along the lines of 'trying to access property `id` of undefined'.

Comment: than user like this section?.id

Comment: Yep doesn't fix the error, I added it to my outermost element and it just moved the error to that line

Comment: I've added the error to the bottom just so we are clear

Comment: Updated Answer please check.

Comment: I'm afraid my answer is far more simple so will be rolling with that

Answer (score -1):

This was easily resolved using the below suggested finally by a friend:

```
section: Section = new Section();
```

to

```
section = new Section();
```

Comment: Correct. This is not a good answer. If you have to remove a type check to make your program work you have way bigger issues. The `any` basically tells TypeScript to back off and allow whatever you put into it.

Comment: I appreciate that it's not the correct answer, but unless you're prepared to offer an alternative solution that actually works then i'm not actually interested.